# Training tensorflow im2txt fails with truncated record at

Tags: python, tensorflow

im2txt trains for a few thousand steps then halts with the following error.
I've checked the training files and they appear OK.

Running on Ubuntu 16.04, TF r.0.11, GPU mode GTX 970 4Gb.

Not sure if it is lack of RAM?

```
INFO:tensorflow:global step 56396: loss = 2.4654 (0.41 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors.DataLossError'>, truncated record at 369740238
     [[Node: ReaderRead = ReaderRead[_class=["loc:@TFRecordReader", "loc:@filename_queue"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordReader, filename_queue)]]

Caused by op u'ReaderRead', defined at:
  File "/home/john/Developer/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/john/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/john/Developer/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 65, in main
    model.build()
  File "/home/john/Developer/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py", line 352, in build
    self.build_inputs()
  File "/home/john/Developer/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py", line 153, in build_inputs
    num_reader_threads=self.config.num_input_reader_threads)
  File "/home/john/Developer/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/ops/inputs.py", line 115, in prefetch_input_data
    _, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
  File "/home/john/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 277, in read
    return gen_io_ops._reader_read(self._reader_ref, queue_ref, name=name)
  File "/home/john/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 211, in _reader_read
    queue_handle=queue_handle, name=name)
  File "/home/john/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 748, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/john/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2403, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/john/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1305, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

DataLossError (see above for traceback): truncated record at 369740238
     [[Node: ReaderRead = ReaderRead[_class=["loc:@TFRecordReader", "loc:@filename_queue"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordReader, filename_queue)]]

INFO:tensorflow:global step 56397: loss = 2.5540 (0.40 sec/step)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, not sure why. I did not see any error when creating tfrecords. During training, the error comes out near the end of the records. BTW I am using tf 0.11rc